# Consider the set $1/n$,$2/n$...$n/n$. Show that there's a 1-1 correspondence between the reduced fractions and the numbers /phi (d) for d|n.

Tags: number-theory

Consider the set $1/n$,$2/n$...$n/n$. Show that there's a 1-1 correspondence between the reduced fractions and the numbers phi (d) for d|n.

Example.
The numbers $1,2,5$ and $10$ all divide $10$.
Phi$(1,2,5,10)$ are 1,1,4, and 4 respectively.

If we consider the fractions 1/10,2/10,3/10...10/10, once we reduce, we will have 1 fraction with a denominator of 1, 1 fraction with denominator 2, 4 fractions with denominator 5 and 4 fractions with denominator 10.

I see the connection, but I don't know how to out it in words.

I am also supposed to show that this proves that every prime p will have phi(p-1) primitive roots.

Comment: Let d\*m = n.  Let (a,d) = 1 and a < d (so a is one of the numbers represented by $\phi(d)$).  The $a*m/n =  a/d$ will have denominator d.  No other fractions b/n  will have a denominator d as a b and d will have a common factor (I need to work on that).    There are $\phi(d)$ numbers less than d that are relatively prime so there is a one to one correspondence between the numbers in $\phi(d) and the fractions with the denominators d.

Answer (score 0):

Let $d|n$. Let $d*m = n$.  $\phi(d)$ are the order of numbers that are less than $d$ and relatively prime to $d$.  Let $a$ be one of those numbers.  The fraction $a*m/n = a/d$ has a denominator of $d$ as $a$ and $d$ are relatively prime.

There are $\phi(d)$ such fractions.

Suppose $b \ne a*m$ for any such $a$ ($gcd(a,d) = 1$ and $a < d$).  Then if $b/n = b'/d$ has denominator d in reduced form then $gcd(b', d) = 1 and $b'm/d*m = b/n$ which contradicts our assumption.  So those fractions are the only ones with d in the denominator.

So there is a 1-1 correspondence between the numbers represented by $\phi(d)$ and the reduced fractions with d in the denominator.